# Spring MVC 3.2 +Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

My requirement is simple i.e i want to write a common methods which suppose to have auto intelligence based on user request it will generate  response, like if i submit as a html it should produce html . if i submit as a Json it should produce Json.
Below is 2 sample code ,If i write 2 separate method it works fine but i want to write it to one common method.

### 1)below is sample code which works for html

```
@Controller
public class Program1Controller {
@RequestMapping("/helloworld")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView helloWord(){
String message = "Welcome to TEST";
return new ModelAndView("Test1", "message",message);
}
}
```

### 2)below is sample code which work for json

```
@RequestMapping(value = DUMMY_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getDummyEmployee() {
String message = "Welcome to TEST";
return message;
}
```

Instead writing 2 separate method i want to write one method which should have auto intelligence to send a response based on user request. 
Above Query for GET ,Same also how can i do for POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that one in ajax. In your controller you have 2 different methods returning JSON, POST and GET and it can have the same value for its RequestMapping. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/returnJSON", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getDummyEmployee() {
String message = "Welcome to TEST";
return message;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/returnJSON", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getDummyEmployee2() {
String message = "Welcome to TEST";
return message;
}
```

This should also be done for the one returning the HTML Object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView helloWord(){
String message = "Welcome to TEST";
return new ModelAndView("Test1", "message",message);
}
} 

 @RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView helloWord2(){
    String message = "Welcome to TEST";
    return new ModelAndView("Test1", "message",message);
    }
    }
```

Now, before going to the jquery ajax call, pass as parameter the url and type:

```
$.ajax({
  type: type,
  url: url,
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```